# @hook and @route not getting executed

Tags: python, ajax, bottle, beaker

I have the  AJAX request sent to the pythonscript "scripts/serverscript.py" ,for some reason @hook('before_request') and 
@route('scripts/serverscript.py') are not geting executed?any inputs on how to debug this and fix the problem?

AJAX call:-

```
    $.ajax({
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                url: "scripts/serverscript.py",
                //data: data,
                data: JSON.stringify(data_SU),
                error   : function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError); 
                    console.log("error return for server");
                },
```

serverscript.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import bottle
from beaker.middleware import SessionMiddleware
from bottle import hook,route
import sys
import json

result = {'success':'true','message':'The Command Completed Successfully'}
myjson = json.load(sys.stdin)
print 'Content-Type: application/json\n\n'
print json.dumps(result)

session_opts = {
    'session.type': 'file',
    'session.data_dir': './session/',
    'session.auto': True,
}

app = SessionMiddleware(bottle.app(), session_opts)

@hook('before_request')
def setup_request():
    result['message'] = r'insetup result'
    print 'Content-Type: application/json\n\n'
    print json.dumps(result)
    request.session = request.environ['beaker.session']

@route('scripts/serverscript.py')
def index():
    result['message'] = r'in - index'
    data = { 'procesing': "in index" }        
    print json.dumps(data)
    if 'processing' in request.session:
        data = { 'procesing': request.session['processing'] }        
        print json.dumps(data)
        return data

    processor()

def processor():
    result['message'] = r'in - processor'
    request.session['processing'] = 1
    #print "in processor"
    # Do some processing here for the first request
    # When processing is done you can clear "state" variable in session
    cherrypick.cp_main()
    del request.session['processing']
    request.session.modified = True
```

Comment: Take Javascript out of the equation. When you hit your server directly, what happens? Does the routing work?

Comment: @ron.rothman - when I run ` python serverscript.py` directly,the script just hangs..

Comment: Yes, isn't that what it's supposed to do? It's a server, after all--it should wait and listen for requests. Am I missing something?

Comment: @ron.rothman - sorry,I missed an input parameter `myjson = json.load(sys.stdin)` ,now it runs fine but only prints the json output outside the `@hook('before_request')` and `@route('scripts/serverscript.py')`

Comment: just to be clear,I meant the problem still exists.

Comment: You're not running the server. You need to call `bottle.run()`.  Consider reading through the nicely written [Bottle tutorial](http://bottlepy.org/docs/0.12/) for an explanation of how to run it.

Comment: why does `bottle.run()` needs to be called explicity?I cant find an example with it

Comment: Do you see the example in the tutorial I linked to, above? It's right there at the top, in the "Hello world" example.

Comment: `from bottle import route, run, template

@route('/hello/<name>')
def index(name):
    return template('<b>Hello {{name}}</b>!', name=name)

run(host='localhost', port=8080)` is all I see,where is `bottle.run()`

Comment: `run` is `bottle.run`

Comment: I get the sense that you're new to Python.  Perhaps you should practice on a less advanced task than this. It's not trivial to get an app server correctly working with an AJAX client. Maybe start on something more straightforward. (Not trying to be condescending, just trying to help guide.)

Comment: @ron.rothman - thanks for all your suggestions,now I get the error http://codeshare.io/e02aL

Comment: @ron.rothman - i fixed the error but I get the following message and hanges.. `{"message": "The Command Completed Successfully", "success": "true"}
Bottle v0.12.8 server starting up (using WSGIRefServer())...
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:8080/
Hit Ctrl-C to quit.
`